# Customizing a packingslip in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I would like to add my company logo and phone number to a packing slip generated by Magento.  Does anyone know how to do this?  When the order confirmation email goes to the customer the company logo is there.  So I know the logo is in Magento.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `System > Configuration > Sales` tab from admin and find the **Invoice and Packing Slip Design** tab on your right.

Here you can upload your own logo in order to be used in order related print out or html.

You can also add your address in this tab, which will appear in your order related docs.

[image]